# Finding a particular string at a specific line number, anywhere in a directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to find instances of the word `package` in line 171 of *any* file in a certain directory. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do, from the directory you want to check, recursively:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c '[[ $(sed -n '171p' "$1") =~ package ]] && echo "$1"' _ {} +
```

this will show you the filenames that contain `package` in their 171-th line.

Non-recursively:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c '[[ $(sed -n '171p' "$1") =~ package ]] && echo "$1"' _ {} +
```

**Example:**

I am looking for `bar`:

```
$ cat foo 
foo
bar

$ find . -type f -exec bash -c '[[ $(sed -n '2p' "$1") =~ bar ]] && echo "$1"' _ {} +
./foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#This will search second line of all the files and grep over them.
#Pass search pattern as argument.

pattern=$1

for file in *

do

cat $file |sed -n '2p' |grep $pattern

done
```